# Java : Which is better - returning an Object property or whole Object

Tags: java, jpa

I have a sequence of function calls like below

```
int empId = saveEmployee(emp);
int deptId = saveDepartment(dept, empId);
int areaId = saveArea(area, deptId);
```

1-My question which is better/ best practice in java to return the Object or its required properties,

```
Employee emp1 = saveEmployee(emp);
Department dept1 = saveDepartment(dept, emp1.getId());
Area area1 = saveArea(area, dept1.getId());
```

Assuming I only need the Id for my next method.

2. And also, does using primitive types increase performance or memory
   consumption.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to me to return a copy of the object you are sending in.

Comment: There is no ID when I send in the Object, I only get it after it is persisted. So the returned object will have ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. My question which is better/ best practice in java to return the
>      Object or its required properties,

I would go with the default result of [`save`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition-tuning) method which return the Object.

```
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
```

and it still a choice for you in this point.

> 2. And also, does using primitive types increase performance or memory consumption.

don't use primitive `int` instead use `Long` for ids, which can hold `null`

Answer (score 0):

As far as i think returning object would be better. As java is object oriented language, best practice is to follow proper access modifiers for each variables with proper getter setter method for each properties.